# AngularJS - Changing a query param term within $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory, route-provider

I am creating a navigation, where when on the active 'link', a feed loads but with a different searched term.

Basically, the all the links are the same, the only difference is the term set in the .factory parameter.

Since everything is the same (even the .controller, is it possible to set the query term inside of the routeProvider, where I can specify the term that needs to be searched?

Or will the only way is to create a new controller for each link, and set the term inside of there? Keeping the code simple, efficient and as little as possible, is what I am trying to aim for.

```
  angular.module('termSearch', ['ngResource'])

  .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = undefined;
  }])

  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/term1', {templateUrl: 'views/feedlist.html', controller: 'searchtermCtrl' })      
      .when('/term2', {templateUrl: 'views/feedlist.html', controller: 'searchtermCtrl' })

      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/term1'});
  })

  .factory('Feed', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('https://www,example.com/:term/json', {}, {
          query: {
              method: 'GET',
              isArray: false,
              params: {
                  term: "term#"
              }
          }
      });  
  })

  .controller('searchtermCtrl', function($scope, Feed){
    $scope.results = Feed.query();
    $scope.feed = function (term) {
        Feed.get({
            term: term
        }, function (results) {
            $scope.results = results
            console.log(results);
        });
    }
  })
```

Thanks for any help in the right direction.

Roc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using resource placeholders and $routeParams you define a hash URL which looks something like this `<a href="#term/search+term+here">Term X</a>`. The search term can be user input or a list of terms from database

```
  angular.module('termSearch', ['ngResource'])

  .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = undefined;
  }])

  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/term/:q', {templateUrl: 'views/feedlist.html', controller: 'searchtermCtrl' })      

      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/term/'});
  })

  .factory('Feed', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('https://www.example.com/:term/json', {}, {
          query: {
              method: 'GET',
              isArray: false
          }
      });  
  })

  .controller('searchtermCtrl', function($scope, Feed, $routeParams){
    $scope.feed = Feed.query({ term : $routeParams.q }); // This will get the term from url
  })
```

Now when the route changes to a new term the resource is send new data parameters

Comment: Thank you Tim! Even less coding than I have intended, and very thorough to follow. Also an FYI or anyone else, and for reference, to target the `:term` inside of the `.factory $resource URL`, swap out the `feed:` inside of the `.controller $scope` to `term:`, or else the new queries will be added to the end of the `$resource URL` Thanks again!

Comment: There is a very good [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) on #angularjs which will give you all the basics and how they work together. cheers to a good javascript framework