# AngularJS - Adding class to $routeProvider placeholder links

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, route-provider

A follow up to the answer provided here: [AngularJS - Changing a query param term within $routeProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946307/angularjs-changing-a-query-param-term-within-routeprovider/18946488#18946488)

When using route params, is it possible to set an 'active' class to the  element or it's parent element? Here is what I've tried, but the 'active' class is not added onto the parent element.

Is the issue that I am facing because of the '/:feed_term' placeholder that I am using?

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/:feed_term', {templateUrl: 'views/feedlist.html', controller: 'searchtermCtrl', activetab: ':feed_term' })      

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/term/'});
})

.controller('searchtermCtrl', function($scope, Feed, $routeParams, $route){
  $scope.feed = Feed.query({ feed : $routeParams.feed_term });
  $scope.activeTab = $route.current.activetab
})
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'feedterm_1'}">
  <a href="#/feedterm_1">Feed 1</a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'feedterm_2'}">
  <a href="#/feedterm_2">Feed 2</a>
</li>
```

Any feedback would greatly be appreciated!

Thanks!
Roc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that your views cannot access data unless it is attached to the scope. Your view accesses `$route.current`, but that data isn't on the scope. Based on the code you've posted, something like this should work:

```javascript
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/:feed_term', {
      templateUrl: 'views/feedlist.html',
      controller: 'searchtermCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/term/'});
})

.controller('searchtermCtrl', function($scope, Feed, $routeParams){
  $scope.feed = Feed.query({ feed : $routeParams.feed_term });
  $scope.activeTab = $routeParams.feed_term
})
```

```html
<li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'feedterm_1'}">
  <a href="#/feedterm_1">Feed 1</a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'feedterm_2'}">
  <a href="#/feedterm_2">Feed 2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, Thanks for the tip. Although this did help when added classes when needed in the view, the navigation is placed outside of the view. If you can take a look at this [link](http://pastebin.com/5B6yxzjr), that would be great. Basically, the navigation is not placed inside the view, so I am trying to target it outside of the view. Thanks btw for checking this question out.

Comment: @Roc You can watch for route changes on the scope by watching for the `$routeChangeSuccess` event. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/gwHat/

Comment: Thanks Brandon! That did the trick. Very grateful for the help and walkthrough.